# Examples of problems in P but with verifiers with many computations

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Let me first specify my question. I am looking for decision problems with polynomial algorithms but such that the simpliest or fastests verifiers do many computations. Here by verifiers I mean both YES and NO verifiers. It might be the case that this is too specific. By "verifiers with many computations" I mean verifiers that use non-trivial computational methods (e.g. dynamic programming, transforms, different methods of computational algebra etc.)

From what I understand most verifiers in $\mathsf{P}$ are either trivial or rely on good characterization theorems but are, themselves, not very complicated algorithms. Is this something to be expected from problems in $\mathsf{P}$? I mean these are the easiest of problems but some have really complicated good characterizations, I would expect that the complexity of the characterization translates somehow to the verifier (but from what I have seen this is not the case).

It might be the case that my question not interesting/stupid but to be honest I cannot see it.

Comment: I'd actually say that most P-complete problems seem to be (at least almost) as hard to verify as they are to solve. Maybe, even all.

Comment: @rus9384 I hadn't really thought of looking at P-complete specifically. Maybe looking at, for example, linear programming (and how such a complicated problem can be boiled down to verifying some simple inequalities) might have hinted that verifiers by nature don't have to do non-trivial computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are none.  For every problem in NP, there is a way to build a verifier such that the verifier is very simple and uses only trivial methods.

Proof: Let $L$ be any language in NP.  Then it has a verifier $V$, such that $x \in L$ iff $\exists y . V(x,y) = \text{true}$.  We call $y$ the certificate or witness.

Now let's construct a new verifier, $V^*$, as follows.  The input to $V^*$ is a pair $(x,y^*)$, where the witness $y^*$ has the form $y^*=(y,(s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2),\dots,(s_k,t_k))$.  Here the second part of $y^*$ is the transcript of the execution of $V$ on input $(x,y)$.  In particular, if $V$ is a Turing machine, then $s_i$ is the finite state it is in, and $t_i$ is the content of the tape, after the $i$th step of execution.  $V^*$ checks whether the transcript is a valid record of an execution starting on input $(x,y)$, and whether it halts with output $\text{true}$.

Now $V^*$ can be implemented by a very simple algorithm, that uses only trivial methods.  The algorithm just checks that each step of execution was done correctly (i.e., looks at $(s_i,t_i)$ and $(s_{i-1},t_{i-1})$).  This is easy to check, given how simple a Turing machine is.  Also, it is efficient.  The running time of $V^*$ is at most the square of the running time of $V$.

Comment: Wow, I kind of felt that you could craft the certificate in a way that is really simple for the verifier to do its thing but looking at the proof like this is really something else. This is too simple, perhaps I'll need to think about the proof a little more to realise its value. Anyhow thank you, but I don't remember ever feeling this bad about a good result.